# Slow boot on Fedora 16: why and how to improve?

Tags: fedora, boot

I recently installed Fedora 16 on a Dell VOSTRO 1510. I am quite happy with it, but I am concerned with the slow boot load time. I measured from launching the OS with GRUB till GDM, a boot load time of `1:01.42`, which I experience as *slow* (that's subjective, my bad: I have not measured other boot times in prior Ubuntu installations, but I remember it to be half that time).

Pressing <kbd>F2</kbd> during boot prints out various details. I notice the boot load is taking much time in the following phase:

```
Started LSB: Starts and stops login ISCSI daemon.
Starting LSB: Starts and stops login and scanning of ISCSI devices.
```

What is LSB, ISCSI? Is one minute indeed a long boot time? Can I somehow improve the boot load time?

Here is my bootchart for more details:

[image: Bootchart]

**Edit:** thanks to some more [documentation](https://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/539856-more-systemd-fun-the-blame-game-and-stopping-services-with-prejudice) suggested by @vasquez, I have been able to remove some services and reduce boot time using `systemd-analyze` and `systemctl`. There are still more services however, which I may need to remove,see below. But how to know what services is doing what and gauge whether I need it or not?

```
 13067ms udev-settle.service
  4622ms fedora-loadmodules.service
  3539ms systemd-vconsole-setup.service
  2913ms remount-rootfs.service
  2620ms media.mount
  2603ms sys-kernel-debug.mount
  2595ms dev-hugepages.mount
  2587ms sys-kernel-security.mount
  2577ms dev-mqueue.mount
  2025ms udev-trigger.service
  1951ms fedora-readonly.service
  1763ms netfs.service
  1619ms mdmonitor-takeover.service
  1598ms fcoe.service
  1570ms udev.service
  1267ms systemd-remount-api-vfs.service
  1214ms fedora-storage-init.service
  1018ms sys-kernel-config.mount
   950ms plymouth-start.service
   833ms systemd-sysctl.service
   440ms NetworkManager.service
   391ms avahi-daemon.service
   324ms rsyslog.service
   268ms systemd-logind.service
   262ms console-kit-log-system-start.service
   249ms fedora-storage-init-late.service
   231ms livesys.service
   228ms ip6tables.service
   224ms iptables.service
   206ms auditd.service
   193ms sshd-keygen.service
   184ms systemd-readahead-replay.service
   183ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
   175ms irqbalance.service
   173ms systemd-readahead-collect.service
   167ms boot.mount
   145ms abrt-vmcore.service
   138ms mcelog.service
   136ms dbus.service
   122ms abrt-ccpp.service
    90ms lvm2-monitor.service
    52ms fedora-wait-storage.service
    51ms sandbox.service
    44ms console-kit-daemon.service
    30ms livesys-late.service
    22ms home.mount
    11ms systemd-user-sessions.service
     9ms accounts-daemon.service
     5ms rtkit-daemon.service
     0ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount
```

**Edit**: After removing the following services:

- sendmail.service
- sm-client.service
- iscsi.service
- udev-settle.service
- fedora-wait-storage.service

Boot went from 1m 1.5s  to about 26s (hurray) see plots:

**Before**

[image: Before]

**After**

[image: After]

Now the `fedora-storage-init.service` is taking the most time and removing it only replaces it by `fedora-storage-init-late.service`. What is this service exactly doing and how it can be sped up is yet a mystery.

Comment: Look inside `/var/log/boot.log` for more info on whats happening at boot time. Maybe you are starting daemons that that fail after a given time (network daemon?). One minute is a bit long.

Comment: @hesse: the log does not give me more information than **F2** did.

Comment: Remove any wireless interfaces. It goes through the wireless interfaces and try to connect to each one, scanning for the AP each time until it times out.  See if that makes a difference.

Comment: If you boot with "log_buf_len=1M systemd.log_level=debug
systemd.log_target=kmsg" a lot more information will be available to you to examine

Comment: @fpmurphy: thanks. You're answer is quite succinct and I can't follow, could you make it a detailed answer? I don't know how to remove wl interfaces scanning from boot nor do I know how to boot the way you suggested.

Comment: [here](http://lwn.net/Articles/299483/) is an old but interesting article on quantifying/reducing startup time, I don't know how much you can apply to the current fedora.  
[LSB](https://admin.fedoraproject.org/pkgdb/acls/name/redhat-lsb) is the Linux Standard Base

Comment: @bdowning: the first link is excellent, it would be great if they'd tell how to get a fast boot too.

Comment: here's my Arch linux, AMD Quad with SATA III SSD [bootchart](http://i.imgur.com/kO9MI)

Comment: @bdowning: wow! :o I want that too!

Comment: A very similar question has comments that describe how to 
produce graphics of the boot process timings:
http://superuser.com/questions/423155/speed-up-my-fedora-16-startup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be worth a try to run `systemd-analyze blame`, see http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/blame-game.html and https://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/539856-more-systemd-fun-the-blame-game-and-stopping-services-with-prejudice.

Those articles also show how to find culprits for long boot time. One minute is too long on F16 as a desktop. I think you should be able to see 20-30 second boot ups.

**Edit:**

LVM does take a lot of time (that's your big initramfs time, but you probably can't get rid of it right away since that would mean a re-install. One services I think you could disable is fcoe.

Another idea from https://plus.google.com/u/0/108087225644395745666/posts/jaFyQtyjZLh :

Add `libahci.ignore_sss=1` to the kernel cmd line:

> Arjan van de Ven  -  +Kay Sievers you want to add "libahci.ignore_sss=1" to the kernel command line... your bios lies to you about the storage, costing you 0.6 seconds.